# Find all real numbers $a$ s.t. $\sum_{k=0}^{2019}\left\lfloor x+\frac{k}{a}\right\rfloor=\lfloor ax\rfloor$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, problem-solving, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

> Find all real numbers $a$ wiith $a\neq 0$ and $$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor+\left \lfloor x+\frac{1}{a} \right  \rfloor+\left \lfloor x+\frac{2}{a} \right  \rfloor+\ldots+\left \lfloor x+\frac{2019}{a} \right  \rfloor=\left \lfloor ax \right  \rfloor,$$
>   $\forall x\in\Bbb R$.

I know that $$\left \lfloor x \right  \rfloor+\left \lfloor x+\frac{1}{a} \right  \rfloor+\ldots+\left \lfloor x+\frac{a-1}{a} \right  \rfloor=\left \lfloor ax \right  \rfloor $$ (Hermite Identity)
   And from here can I make the conclusion that the only solution is 2020?
   I think that there might be multiple solutions. Can somebody tell me if there are other solutions? Thank you.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: It's form a math a romanian math magazine for contests and olympiads. I will add a photo if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\left [ x \right ]+\left [ x+\frac{1}{a} \right ]+\left [ x+\frac{2}{a} \right ]+...+\left [ x+\frac{2019}{a} \right ].$$

Now $$f\left(x+\frac{1}{a}\right)=\left [ x+\frac{1}{a} \right ]+\left [ x+\frac{2}{a} \right ]+...+\left [ x+\frac{2020}{a} \right ]$$

$$f\left(x+\frac{1}{a}\right)-f(x)= \left [ x+\frac{2020}{a} \right]-\left [ x \right ]$$

$$\Rightarrow \left [ a(x+\frac{1}{a})\right]  -\left [ ax \right ]= \left [ x+\frac{2020}{a} \right]-\left [ x \right ]$$

$$\left [ x+\frac{2020}{a} \right]-\left [ x \right ]=1$$

Can you find the conditions now? And most importantly keep in mind it should be an identity in $x$.

Comment: $\left [ x+\frac{2020}{a} \right ]=1+\left [ x \right ] \in Z$ Then I considered 1+[x]=k , $k\in Z$ [x]=1-k , then $$1-k\leq x< 2-k$$ then I got stuck, because i cant put x back in $\left [ x+\frac{2020}{a} \right ]$. How can I solve it?

Comment: It can only be an identity in x when $\frac{2020}{a} \in$ integers, which leaves us with only one solution a=2020

Comment: ok thank you, I understood.

Comment: @Sd100 You are welcome